# read() return extra characters from file

Tags: c, string, file, io

I am trying to read text from file to print.. While trying if I give the char buffer size it returns some extra character ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){

    int fd = open("text.txt",O_RDONLY);

    char cbuffer[100];
    int a =0;
    if(fd>0){
        puts("File open");
        ssize_t len = read(fd,cbuffer,sizeof(cbuffer));
        a =printf("%s",&cbuffer);
        printf("\n return data count  %d",a);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

If instead of

```
ssize_t len = read(fd,cbuffer,sizeof(cbuffer));
```

to

```
ssize_t len = read(fd,cbuffer,10);
```

returns 10 chars exactly . 
Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: I'm pretty sure read doesn't null terminate the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because, `read()` does not null-terminate the output. You need to null-terminate the destination buffer before using it as a *string*.

Basically passing a non-null terminated `char` array to `printf()` as the argument to `%s` creates [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as there can be out of bound memory access.

One way of achieving this is to `0`-initialize the destination. That way, it will be considered null-terminated after the valid values read and stored by `read()`. Something like

```
  char cbuffer[100] = {0};
```

can help.

That said, change

```
 printf("%s",&cbuffer);
```

to

```
printf("%s",cbuffer);
```

as `%s` expects a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char`s. When you pass the array name to a function, it decays to the pointer to the first element, so you should be ok.

Comment: I read "*extra characters*" and immediately thought, there is no *null* terminator and the OP is using `printf()` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two problems.

1. Strings in [c](/questions/tagged/c) consist of a sequence of non `null` bytes followed by a `null` byte. The `null` byte indicates that there will be no more bytes in the *string*. It's not impossible but unusual that the `null` byte would be stored in the file, furthermore if the file is a text file it's almost sure that it will not contain the necessary `null` byte. If you simply want to display the content of the file you could output data using functions that like `read()` do not care about the `null` byte and instead take the number of available bytes as a parameter, example

   ```
   ssize_t length = read(fd, cbuffer, sizeof(cbuffer);
   if (length == -1)
       return do_something_an_error_occurred();
   else
       write(STDOU_FILENO, cbuffer, length);
   ```
2. You are passing the address of the array to `printf()`

   ```
   printf("%s",&cbuffer);
   ```

   that's wrong because when `printf()` finds a `"%s"` specifier it expects the passed parameter to be a `char *` pointer but you have passed a pointer to an array of `char`. An array is automatically converted to a pointer when passed as a parameter, and in general nothing special needs to be done to convert an array to a pointer.

   This is by definition: undefined behavior, and you must note that when you incremente the address of the array it will be incremented by the size of a pointer whereas incrementing the array it self —since it will be a pointer of the type of the array elements— you increment by the size of an element.

**ADVICE**: Don't use the `'\n'` at the beginning of a line, it's called the end of line character for a reason. It instructs the `printf()` to flush the file stream it is writing to, ergo it should be the last character in the format string.